# Some Airport-Codes not working

Tags: amadeus

in all Amadeus Self-Service APIs only some Airport codes work. For example "FRA" works, but "TXL" doesn't. Is this because the API is in Beta and I only use the Sandbox version?

Example:

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations?origin=FRA&oneWay=false&nonStop=false

**WORKS**

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations?origin=TXL&oneWay=false&nonStop=false

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 500,
      "code": 141,
      "title": "SYSTEM ERROR HAS OCCURRED",
      "detail": "DATA DOMAIN NOT FOUND FOR REQUEST"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIs available in the test environment  have a limit set of data (cache or fake data).

In the test environment, this API doesn't have data for TXL as origin, for Germany you have FRA and MUC.

So far our data set covers more the US and some big cities in the world. We will publish soon the list of available data on our portal.

You can find the list of available data in the test environment on our [GitHub page](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection).